# issues with a for loop in a user entered array

Tags: java, arrays

This is obviously homework but I am having issues with part of the assignment here is that part

"Start by asking the user for how many double values do they want you to read in.  Then allows them to input them one at a time.  An exception should be thrown if given faulty values.  You will store the values read in into an array."

The issue I am having is with the for loop that asks for the user to input the numbers that they want it throws 5 errors I can't figure out or is there an easier way to get user input?. Here is that code for that

```
//import statements
import java.util.*;     //for scanner class


// class beginning
class  StandardDev {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    //Declare variables area
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    //Collect inputs from user or read in data here
    System.out.println("Welcome to my Standard Deviation and average program!");
    System.out.println("how many numbers do you want to enter? ");
    int number =input.nextInt();
    double [] value = new double [number];


    //Echo input values back to user here
    System.out.println("you want to enter in "+number+" numbers, lets start");


    //main code and calculations to do

    int i;
    for ( i = 0;, i <number;, i++){
        value[i] = input.nextDouble();
        System.prinln("here are the numbers you have entered "+value+"!");
    }
    //Output results here
```

and if anyone can tell me how to check if the number entered isn't a valid input (is it any different if this wasn't an array?) and am I correctly entering in doubles for the program?

Comment: To start with, remove the commas from `for ( i = 0;, i <number;, i++){`

Comment: They're semi colons and commas

Comment: Right. I'm saying remove the commas (and keep the semicolons). The commas are incorrect.

Comment: It would really help if you post the stacktrace, it would be easier for us to find the error of your code

Comment: @morbidCode: Hard to have a stacktrace for code that won't compile. :-)

Comment: to check a double is valid refer to the javadoc for Double method valueOf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to fix your for statement removing the commas and using System.out.println rather than System.prinln

In this way:

```
for ( i = 0; i <number; i++){
    value[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println("Here are the numbers you have entered "
    + Arrays.toString(value) + " !");
```

The result will be:

> Welcome to my Standard Deviation and average program! 
>   how many numbers do you want to enter?
>
> 3
>
> you want to enter in 3 numbers, lets start
>
> 1 2 3
>
> here are the numbers you have entered [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]!

**About the validation:**

You can modify your for statement in this way in order to catch wrong input and allow the user to re-enter the value:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < number) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the value " + (i+1) + "/" + number + ":");
        value[i] = input.nextInt();
        i++;
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("This is not a valid input! Please enter it again!");
        input.next();   // This consume the invalid token
    }
}
```

This is the final result:

> Welcome to my Standard Deviation and average program!
>
> how many numbers do you want to enter?
>
> 3
>
> you want to enter in 3 numbers, lets start
>
> Enter the value 1/3:
>   1
>
> Enter the value 2/3:
>   2
>
> Enter the value 3/3:
>   a
>
> This is not a valid input! Please enter it again!
>
> Enter the value 3/3:
>   3
>
> Here are the numbers you have entered [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] !

Comment: That `int number` is for sizing the array, and the first part of your answer is directly taken from my answer without attribution.

Comment: DO NOT use try catch to validate a double. use regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop syntax is a little off, and you should print your array after you read in all of the user's values.

```
// main code and calculations to do
int i;
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    value[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
```

Also, with the `for` loop it's considered better to limit the scope of the iterating variable `i` and to use `println` you need `System.out` (not just `System`) and you need a `String` (Java arrays do not override `toString()`) so something to output the numbers the user entered (after the loop) like

```
// main code and calculations to do
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    value[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println("here are the numbers you have entered "
        + Arrays.toString(value) + "!");
```

Comment: I was just coming back here to ask if there was a better way after I fixed my stupid error I ran the program but whenever I enter in a number it spits out this
"here are the numbers you have entered [D@55f96302!"

Comment: @WebCobra Read my answer again. Pay attention to the part about `Arrays.toString(value)`